# How can I create a word uniqueness score from normalized text

Tags: probability-theory, formal-languages

I currently have song lyrics in the form of normalized tokens stored in a database.

I have computed both the total amount of unique words, and the word count per song. I am currently (and crudely) calculating the lyrical uniqueness of a song by the following formula:

unique words / total words = uniqueness score 
where 1.0 is every word is unique and 0.00 = all words are the same

The problem is, that as songs get longer, they are more likely to repeat words, thus longer songs will still reflect a poor uniqueness score despite still having a large and vocabulary interesting vocabulary, and on the other end, very short songs don't repeat words often, and can be rated as more unique than they should be.

I am trying to write a program that take into account how long the song is when calculating the uniqueness. I do understand how to correlate the size of total words to unique words, but I don't know what to do after that. How do I factor in my correlation coefficient into my 0.0-1.0 rating system? Ideally, I'd like to take the unique word count and total word count as parameters, apply my formula, and then assign a handicap based off of the total amount of words.

I don't have a formal academic math background, so it's hard to even know how to ask the right question. Sorry if I am being to obtuse! (pun intended)

Comment: This question is much better suited for math stack exchange.  Math overflow is for questions of interest to professional mathematicians.  If you have to apologize for lack of academic math background, that is fine at stack exchange but not here.

Answer (score 1):

You might consider something like
$$
\text{lyrical uniqueness} = 
\left(
\frac{\text{unique words}}{\text{total words}}\right)^{1/\text{length}} .
$$
Then longer songs with the same unique fraction will have lyrical uniqueness scores nearer $1$.

This function is modifiable. You can try multiplying the unique fraction by a constant between $0$ and $1$ (so even a song with all unique words won't have a lyrical score of $1$). You can multiply length by a factor, or raise it to a power, to adjust the rate at which longer songs  increase the uniqueness quotient to get the lyrical uniqueness. Play until you get a measure that matches your subjective judgment.